# Removing Shadows from Aerial Imagery in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcgis-10.2, digital-image-processing, shadow

I am creating an automatic change detection tool in Python for ArcGIS 10.2 using aerial imagery.  The tool works but it also detects shadow change. I have been able to create a classified raster of just shadows and tried using raster calculator to eliminate the shadows using the Con statement and subtraction without success. Is there a way to remove shadows from an aerial image or make those areas NoDATA, using the tools in ArcGIS and Python.  I read about histogram matching and using a mask to eliminate shadows though I am not sure how to go about doing this.

Comment: Are you looking to replace the shadow areas with different images?

Comment: If it is possible.  I was thinking about using the surrounding non-shadow imagery to replace the shadow areas.

Comment: What type of imagery are you working with?

Comment: Its a 4 band orthoimagery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For satellite imagery this would usually be done using an elevation model and time of capture to calculate which areas are in the shadow of mountains/hilltops etc. These areas could then be adjusted/normalized according to different methods. You can read more about this here:

- [Removing shadows](http://www.cs.utah.edu/~shirley/papers/snowTerrain/terrain-node7.html)

Some methods also take into account indirect light (reflexes) from surrounding areas. A water body or a glacier could for example give more light to some shaded areas than others:

- [First Landsat 8 images of Antarctica](http://blog.imagico.de/first-landsat-8-images-of-antarctica/)

One way of solving your challenge would be to calculate shadow areas at the time of capture and then use the calculated areas to mask out potential shadow areas. This is done by setting the areas to NoData. The following information might help you to do this:

- [Esri: Setting values to NoData with Set Null](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z0000000m000000.htm)

Comment: Thanks for the information. Once I classify the shadow areas, which image processing techniques are used to remove them from the image?

Comment: Use the shadow areas and "delete" them from your original imagery. From what I understand this could be done by setting the shaded areas to NoData value. Will add reference in answer.

Comment: It worked. Do I use the surrounding pixel values to "fill in" the NoData areas?

Comment: It depends on what your aim is to do. Perhaps you could experiment a bit and see what represents reality in the best way? In any way as long as you document your method in the product specification or similar you should be fine.