# Correct for tree shadows to reveal that which is cast in shadow

Tags: r, arcgis-pro, classification, habitat-modeling, shadow

I am mapping suitable habitat for a threatened plant species.

I acquired NAIP images from 2016, 2018, and 2020, classified the imagery according to different types of habitat, and would now like to analyze the % cover change in certain types of habitat. However, there are tree shadows that obscure parts of the landscape. Also, each image was taken at a different time of day, so the shadow is in a different position for each image.

I could use one image to correct the shadow of another, but do not want to bias my analysis of habitat change.

I could classify the shadows as unsuitable habitat, or mask it out. But the shadows do move throughout the day, so it would be ideal to correct the tree shadows and reveal that cast in shadow. Is there a way to do this?

I have included an example in screenshot. I use ArcGIS Pro and R.
[image: Example showing tree shadows]

Comment: You can remove the shadows https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/149326/removing-shadows-from-aerial-imagery-in-arcgis

Comment: You'd need overlapping imagery taken at a different time of day/season to glean what is hidden in shadow, but lack of data can't be corrected with impunity.

Comment: I initially came across the linked post, but I gathered that this referred to DEMs, where the peaks and valleys of the surface create shadows and I use hillshading in part of the correction. BTW, the link to 'Removing shadows' is broken. Also, the data I would need to model 'no shadow' (as @Vince suggests) is needed as part of the multidimensional raster I want to create. Thank you anyway folks!